# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, docker

I have an application `app` run on MacOS in docker using this command

```
docker-compose up
```

All credentials are defined in docker-compose file.
Now I have to manually create tables in database from file `db25.sql`. `Digital` is the name of my database.
When I type this command:

```
mysql -u user -p Digital < db25.sql
```

and type a password I get the error:

**ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

I tried restarting mysql and all commands which I found in the internet but nothing worked and I still get the error.